# Masking login credentials in Kafka Connector does not work

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

These are the steps I've done:

1. Added these 2 lines to connect-standalone.properties (added to distributed one too)

> ```
>  config.providers=file
>
>  config.providers.file.class=org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
> ```

2. Created a file and added username and password

> ```
>  /kafka/vty/pass.properties
>  
>  con_usr=XXXXX
>
>  con_pwd=XXXXX
> ```

3. Created connector with values from file

> ```
> "connection.user": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:con_usr}",
> "connection.password": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:con_pwd}",
> ```

Still it gives the "Invalid username/password" error. I tried giving the credentials in pass.properties both with and without quote marks but same result. It connects without any problems when I do it with no masking.

Comment: how are you masking the credentials, you mean encoding? The properties you added are to ask Kafka not to log the confidential information in logs.

Comment: Not encoding, just want to hide it in logs as you said. Instead of giving the credentials directly, it will read them from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding FileConfigProvider lines to "connect-standalone.properties", which is located in /kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/kafka. But instead, I needed to edit the "connect-avro-distributed.properties" file in /kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/schema-registry/.

This solved the problem, I didn't know this file was being used as config. If anyone faces the same problem, you may want to check how Kafka Connect was created.

Answer (score 0):

I know mine is a little different approach, but maybe it can help. I have created a simple class that maps a section of the `appsettings.json` file, in which you store the userid and password.

appsettings.json section is:

```
  "Kafka": {
    "UserId": "user",
    "Password": "pw"
    "GroupId": "groupname",
    "...", "..."
  },
```

The Kafkaconfiguration is a simple:

```
public class Kafkaconfiguration
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

In the CreateHostBuilder() function I added these lines:

```
   var kafkaConfiguration = new Kafkaconfiguration();
   hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Kafka").Bind(kafkaConfiguration);
```

And then you have the credentials in the kafkaConfiguration properties